# I am using a lot of variables to count time in my game ,is it ok?

Tags: java, android, game-physics, mobile-development

In my game i have timer variables for every thing that happen in my game for example timer for counting seconds till i create an enemy and deploy it and timer for any enemy to shoot .. my point here is that i am using a lot of variables of type long.

```
long timeToEnemyShoot = System.nanoTime();
while (true){
     update();
}

public void update(){
if( System.nanoTime() - timeToEnemyShoot) / 1000000 >= 1000 ){
     enemy.shoot();
}
```

and just imagine that there's more than 15 variable like that !
and i think this is not a good way to manage time.
So is there any other efficient way ?

Comment: You need what you need... ;o) The better question is: are they at the right places? But we need to see your code (or at least a sample) to tell that.

Comment: Ask yourself whether it is possible to achieve the outcome without the data, i.e. using data from other sources. If the answer is no, then you'll need to keep it. The time complexity of deriving values from others may outweigh the space complexity of storing it.

Comment: without code we can't tell you if its ok or not :)

Answer (score 0):

I think its generally OK. Maybe using sort of a milestone long variable and to specify exact time you will use milestone + less memory consuming variable. Risks are complexity =>  bugs, higher computing requirements.

Answer (score 0):

When declaring a variable , `memory allocation` takes place for the variable.

Thing you can make sure inorder to save you a lot of pain in the long run is that to make variable `private`.
In some case types of access will affect performance.

I hope this helps.